# Multiple voices in Lilypond: stem directions, beams, and merged noteheads

Tags: guitar, notation, lilypond

With quite a bit of trial and error I figured out a way to write the following bar in Lilypond:

[image]

There are four voices, the top voice has upward stems, the two lower voices have downward stems, and the stems of the middle voice (in eighth notes) should be chosen as if there were no other voices. Furthermore, the notes of the middle voice should be beamed per beat.

This is the code:

```
\new Staff  \relative c' {
  \key b \minor
  \time 3/4
  \clef "treble_8"
  \mergeDifferentlyHeadedOn

<< { \voiceOne d2 d4 } \\
   { \voiceTwo s4 fis,2 } \\
   { \voiceThree \stemNeutral d'8[ b] fis[ b] d[ b] } \\
   { \voiceFour b,2. } >> |
}
```

I think the code is quite clumsy and I was wondering if there is a more elegant and efficient way to do this. There are still about 50 similar bars to come ...

I would be very curious to know how someone with better Lilypond skills than me would solve such a problem.

Comment: Just FYI, the normal standard would be that you have two different note heads--a solid one for the eighth notes and an unfilled one for the half note. The eighth notes would also be slightly separated from the half note. I understand if you're avoiding that intentionally for a cleaner look. But I just wanted to mention the possibility.

Comment: @trlkly: Yes, I know, but I think it looks indeed much cleaner that way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have 50 similar bars, I would definitely separate each voice into its own variable. The usual way to go about this is making a variable that contains the things that you want to have in each voice, like this:

```
global = {
    \key b \minor
    \time 3/4
    \mergeDifferentlyHeadedOn
    \mergeDifferentlyDottedOn
    % whatever else you prefer
}
```

Then you make a variable for each voice, and you include the `global` variable into the voice like this

```
one = {
    \global    % this inserts the whole content of the "global" variable
    \voiceOne
    d2 d4 |
    e2 e4 |   % I made up some more notes
    cis2 cis4 |
    % etc.
}
```

and you make variables for all the other voices in a similar way. Then you combine them together:

```
\score
{
    \new Staff <<
        \clef "G_8"  % shorter than "treble_8", that's all
        \new Voice \one
        \new Voice \two
        \new Voice \three
        \new Voice \four
    >>
    \layout { }
    \midi { } % only if you want MIDI output
}
```

In this way, you have four voices, each of them is filled in from one variable (here, they are called `\one` through `\four` but you can use more imaginative names). It's a pretty clean solution (you can even split it into multiple files easily) because you can "factor out" the common stuff into the `\global` variable (again, you can call this variable however you want) and often you can easily make use of things like `\repeat unfold` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's indeed neater. The disadvantage for me is just that the code for a single bar is then spread out over the source file (one part per voice). But I guess there is no way around that, or is there?

Comment: @MattL. - I don’t think there’s a way around that. On the other hand, as far as I know, LilyPond is not designed to work this way — at least not at scale. Using `<<{}\\{}>>` should be temporary, not fundamental to the coding of the piece. If I understand correctly, every time `<<{}\\{}>>` is used, LilyPond silently adds at least two additional `Voice` contexts to your `\score`. One `<<{}\\{}>>` for every measure could end up basically creating hundreds of `Voice` contexts and make the application choke. Ask me how I know.

Comment: @MattL. — I don't think so either. And I would actually argue that it's (mostly) better to have it this way. Removing whole bars is more difficult, that's true, but otherwise, you keep together things that musically belong together. Then you can make good use of `\repeat unfold`, automatic filling of notes/durations etc. (For extreme case, imagine an orchestral score with 20 instruments interleaved like in your snippet. Things like "I need to change the violins to play this melody in these 4 bars" become a nightmare.)

Comment: Re "the code for a single bar is then spread out over the source file": have a look at \parallelMusic. Re "could end up basically creating hundreds of `Voice` contexts and make the application choke": did you witness it choking? I don't see why those extra `Voice` contexts would be particularly more expensive compared to the objects LilyPond already has to create to typeset the music.

Comment: @ABOUSAMRAJean: Thanks for pointing out \parallelMusic, didn't know about this.

Comment: @ABOUSAMRAJean - To my understanding, yes, it choked. I found this -> https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-lilypond/2019-03/msg00003.html <- which discussed the same behavior I was witnessing.

Comment: That's interesting. Now, they say on that thread that this is a common problem, and I have never heard about it in several years now watching LilyPond lists, so it might have been fixed in the meantime (didn't search commit history, though).